# Designing API to start and stop a process with Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I am developing a REST web server with Java and Jersey. This is my first web application and I want to be sure that I am structuring the application well. I created my first function which is working well:

```java
@Path("/startAuto") 
public class Rest {

    @GET
    public String startAuto() {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/startAuto.sh");
            Process p = pb.start();     
            p.waitFor();                
            return ("Auto Started");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ("error");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add a new function like `stopAuto`.

Which is cleaner: adding the function in this class or create a new class?

Comment: It depends on the endpoint path you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Approach 1

The [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) method should be used for retrieving information. Don't use [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) to change a state of a resource. Prefer [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) instead.

So, you'll have something as following:

- Start the process:

```
POST /auto/start HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

- Stop the process:

```
POST /auto/stop HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

With this approach, you will have the following in your resource class:

```java
@Path("/auto")
public class Rest {

    @POST
    @Path("/start")
    public String start() {
        ...
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/stop")
    public String stop() {
        ...
    }
}
```

### Approach 2

REST is protocol independent and is a [resource-oriented](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) architecture. When implementing REST applications over the HTTP protocol, for example, the resource is identified by the URI and the operation over the resource is expressed by the [HTTP method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4).

With this approach, the new state of the resource will be expressed in the request payload using JSON, for example. To obtain the state of a resource, use [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) and to replace the state of a resource, use [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4).

You could have the following:

- Start the process:

```
PUT /auto/status HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "value" : "started"
}
```

- Stop the process:

```
PUT /auto/status HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "value" : "stopped"
}
```

- Get the status of the process:

```
GET /auto/status HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

Your resource class will be like:

```java
@Path("/auto/status")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Rest {

    @PUT
    public String changeStatus(Status status) {
        ...
    }
    
    @GET
    public Status getStatus() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And that's what the `Status` class will look like:

```java
public class Status {

    private String value;
    
    // Default constructor, getters and setters omitted
}
```

### Response status codes

You certainly will need to inform your client about the result of the operation. To do it, use the [HTTP response status codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6).

A few status that might be useful:

- [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1): Use this status to indicate that the request has succeeded.
- [`202`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3): Use this status code to indicate the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.
- [`204`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5): Use this status code to indicate the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body.
- [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8): Use this indicates that the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource.

Answer (score 2):

As peeskillet points out in his comment, it depends on how you want to structure your URLS

If you wanted something like

/auto/start and

/auto/stop

I would go for all in one class structured as follows

```
@Path("/auto") 
public class Rest {

    @GET
    @Path("/start")
    public String startAuto() {

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/stop")
    public String stopAuto() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but I think grouping them by "Responsibility" is much better than grouping by URL.  That should ensure that related logic is close to each other. Though ideally, URLs should also be clubbed as per functionality/responsibility

Comment: I agree - but with such a small example it's difficult to determine where any responsibly boundaries lie.

Answer (score 0):

Good structure is essential to any good project/product, however it is also a question whose answers vary from situation to situation. 
However, if in doubt, a good starting point is to group your endpoints as per "**responsibilities**". If they belong together, then put them in the same class.

*Personal Opinion* : Boundary-Control-Entity is the simplest starting point that I could find for starting a project. The structure then adapts as per need. Take a look at this [article](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/bureaucratic_design_with_java_ee) from Adam Bien for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is better to put another function related with the current resource into the same class.

But you should also remember that REST operates with resources but not with functions (nouns but not verbs). So probably it makes sense to make your API more RESTfull:

1. You target resource this is an auto. So it could be accessible by the URL "/auto"
2. Functions "start" and "stop" is used to change the state of resource. So it means that you have a "sub-resource" of the auto that could be accessed by URL "/auto/state" with possible values, for instance "started", "stopped". This values is accessible by GET:/auto/state
3. Now it is possible to change the state with a REST style using PUT/POST request with a status value in the body (also it is possible to use PATCH method in order to partially update auto). Probably, at your case, it makes sense to leave only one method exposed as an endpoint which consumes status value and call logic for starting or stopping the auto in accordance with parameter.